# Cannot get a logo to resize to a certain height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to incorporate a logo into a HTML page, but I cannot seem to get its height to auto resize to a max-height of 140px. When I do, the logo gets chopped off. See this for this example:

```css
.partner-logo {
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  margin-top: 20%;
  max-height: 140px;
  left: 96px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="partner-logo">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

How can I make sure that this logo can have 100% width but only a max height of 140px?

Comment: Why the big top margin? Also, why max-height instead of just height?

Comment: It's being integrated into another piece of code. I didn't want to specifically set a height because this will be used with multiple logos and I just don't want them to exceed a certain height.

Answer (score 2):

Please try applying `background-size: contain` property to your css. `background-size: contain` scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

For more about `background-size` property see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```css
.partner-logo {
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  margin-top: 20%;
  max-height: 140px;
  left: 96px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="partner-logo">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I changed the max-height to just 5px in jsfiddle and the image size stayed the same.

Comment: Hi LewlSauce, in the question you have mentioned max-height as 140px.

Comment: Thanks Ritu. I know -- just wanted to see if I could modify the number as well if needed rather than hard coding it. I was able to make it work with your solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**This** css code **makes sure your background is always centered and always fit the size you give your div** without it getting "chopped off":

```
        .partner-logo {
            background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
    
            background-position: center;
            background-size: contain;

            margin-top: 20%;
            max-height: 140px;
            left: 96px;
            z-index: 1;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

Comment: What does this explain?

Comment: This css code makes sure your background is always centered and always fit the size you give your div without it getting "chopped off".

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and you can resize the image. Just increase or decrease the padding value.
thanks and hope this help you.

```css
.partner-logo {
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px; 
  margin-top: 20%;
  max-height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="partner-logo"></div>
```